# What to do with open ended "experience" questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Two questions, both of the form "Have you had any experience with X", with **no further elaboration**. One is [promptly closed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/any-experience-with-invensense-imu), the other gets [many votes and answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/psoc-by-cypress).  The partial answer to why on the latter seems fairly obvious, people can easily speak to it as is fairly common.

However, then why was the former closed?  If the other question is OK as-is, shouldn't the appropriate action to take with the less-popular product question to simply let it be?

Is this double standard OK?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the other open question is from **ONE YEAR AGO** and was imported from the SE 1.0 site question corpus, so I am not sure it is entirely fair to draw parallels. :)

It is absolutely true that the advice in the FAQ explicitly discourages this form of question:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

> #### What kind of questions should I not ask here?
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite _____?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use _____ for _____, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if _____ happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “_____ sucks, am I right?”
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about _____”, then you should not be asking here. If your motivation is “I would like others to explain _____ to me”, then you are probably OK.